# facebook share not giving response

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

I know there are hundreds of questions related to this and mostly with answers but none of them seems to work with me.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : #{FbAppId},
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };

$(document).on('click', '#share_dialog_open',function(){
    var imageurl = $(this).attr('image_url');
    var blog_description = $(this).attr('descr');
    var blog_title = $(this).attr('blog_title');
    var blogid = $(this).attr('blogid');
    var vb_id = $(this).attr('vb_id');

    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      link: "http://URL/" + vb_id,
      picture: imageurl,
      description: blog_description,
      title: blog_title
    }, function(response){
      console.log(response);
      alert(response);
      if(response && !response == undefined){
        window.location="/congrats"
      }
    });
});
```

In console.log i'm getting nothing and in alert(response) I keep getting either one these (undefined, [], [object Object])

Any kind of help of would be appreciated.

And I have also in my Omniauth.rb

```
provider :facebook, "#{FbAppId}", "#{FbAppSecret}", {:scope => 'email publish_actions email manage_pages publish_pages'}
```

Comment: That you get nothing in console, but the alert using the same object in the very next line does output something … that is very unlikely. More likely that you _miss_ what gets printed to console, because you are redirecting away from the page (an alert will "pause" that, console.log does not) directly after. So remove that redirection, and check again.

Comment: @CBroe buddy this is working perfectly fine if I remove alert, console or not remove. The main issue is I'm not getting response after I click on cancel button on pop up or even if I click on share.

Comment: Share gating is not allowed.

Comment: @WizKid What do you mean ?

Comment: the if block is nonsense, and what do you actually want to achieve? why redirect after share? maybe the user wants to use the share button again to share it elsewhere? also, do not use alert for debugging. use console.log and proper debug tools (chrome dev tools, for example) to inspect objects in the console.

Comment: btw, you so not need publish_actions or publish_pages to use the feed dialog. in fact, you do not even need to authorize the user.

Comment: I mean you are not allowed to show the user something different just because they share

Comment: @luschn Yea I know but I can't simply do that because there is no way to go to the next page in my app the only way is to go from share.

Comment: @WizKid I can see a lot of s/o answers where user's are getting response in ` function(response){
      if(response && !response == undefined){
        window.location="/congrats"
      }`

But don't know why i'm gettin nothing

Comment: Doesn't matter if you finding a bunch of different answer. I'm saying it is not allowed.

Comment: You need to go read platform policy. https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse - 4.5 is the want you want to pay extra attention to.

Comment: "there is no way to go to the next page in my app the only way is to go from share" - as other users already mentioned, you are forcing/incentivizing people to share something, that´s not allowed.

Comment: @luschn yea buddy i'm talking about that only. That after some one share it still don't redirect me

Comment: i think you are missing the point: what you want to achieve is not allowed. if the only way to get to some content is to share something ("share gating")...the only answer you will get for that is: "read the platform policy"

Comment: So it's not possible whether I use ` method: 'share', method: 'feed' ` or with ` https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=******&display=popup `  No matter what The response after I hit on post to facebook will not come ??

Comment: And the main issue i'm facing is on some systems it is working fine means: the response after hitting cancel and after click post to facebook is coming but for some it's not.
and this is what facebook documentation said:
"Note that response.error_message will appear only if someone using your app has authenciated your app with Facebook Login."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone, who got the same problem with new API and eventually somehow came here in search for answer. Here is how I solved it.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : #{FbAppId},
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'    // don't_use_greater_version
    });
  };


FB.ui({
      method: 'feed', // don't use share you won't get anything in response
      link: "your_url_which_you_want_to_share,
      picture: path_to_your_image,
      description: your_description,
      title: your_title
    }, function(response){
      console.log(response);
      if (response == undefined || response == null) {
        return
      }
      else if (response.length == 0 || !response.error_code) {
        where_you_want_to_redirect
      }
    });
```